# Blender rescaling rendered images issue

Tags: blender

I recently rendered an image in blender. Now, the issue is, when I down scale the image the quality seems to lower as I can identify individual pixels. I'm not entirely sure if this is aliasing (and if it is, it would be nice if someone could explain *how* this is caused by aliasing) and whether setting anti-aliasing in blender would work. See below:

Before

[image]

After[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How do you have scaled the image? Usually you can choose between several algorithms, such as bicubic, Lanczos or nearest neighbour (the worst) but those seem compression artifacts too.

Comment: I selected the image then dragged it smaller :/ Didn't actually try in a proper editor but I will later

Answer (score 0):

Your answer isn't directly related to blender, since you're resizing the image inside microsoft paint, this program manage how the pixels are stored/rendered over screen and in most of the cases, shrinking or increase the resolution of an image, also mean that you're going to lose detail/quality, try another image manipulation program and check the results, there are some [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling#Algorithms) that perform the resampling of an image, each of them performs some mathematical operation over pixel, approximation, multiplication between neighbors pixels and so on. different programs have their different features for this.